# SignalR (5.0.6) not working on IIS, works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I'm trying to connect up to a web socket connection via signalR. It works fine on local. The older version even works fine deployed on the same machine (simultaneously). That is important because the servers (2) are behind AWS Load balancer.

Error message reads this:

WebSocket connection to ''wss://stg-api.guestbell.com/hubs/main?role-type=1&access_token=eyJhbG...' failed

When I open the network WS section on Chrome I see status 'finished' and no other errors. That is imho weird as I would expect 401/500... or something like that when it doesn't work.

Code:
Frontend:

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(
      Config.apiUrl +
        Config.signalRMainPath +
        '?role-type=' +
        RoleTypeEnum.Guest,
      {
        accessTokenFactory: () => store.getState().oidc.user?.access_token,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        // I've tried various combinations of these
        /*skipNegotiation: true,
        withCredentials: true,*/
      }
    )
    .withAutomaticReconnect({
      nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: retryContext => {
        return Math.random() * 10000 + 5000;
      },
    })
    .build();
...
await connection.start();
```

Backend:

```
// Configure services
var signalRBuilder = services.AddSignalR();
// Configure
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
  app.UseSimulatedLatency(
    min: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
    max: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)
  );
} else {
  app.UseHsts();
  app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
  OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
    const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
      "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
  }
});
app.UseSignalRQueryStringAuth();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
  endpoints.MapHub < SignalRMainCore > ("/hubs/main");
  endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I don't know where is my problem ?

I am using :

"@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.6"

Other relevant info:

Dotnet version on the machine:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.203
 Commit:    383637d63f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.6
  Commit:  478b2f8c0e

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Edit:

I noticed something strange. When I copy the websockets URL and paste it to the browser (replacing the wss to https) i get:

```
Cannot change transports mid-connection
```

On the page where it works (makes sense, error obviously comes from the signal r)

but when I do the same with the page that doesn't work, I get the standard IIS 404:
[image: 404]

Now that seems suspicious ... like IIS is somehow hijacking the HTTP pipeline. Weird thing is the same code works on IIS on my local machine. Both express and proper.

It might be red herring ... I don't know

Edit 2:
Small extra piece of info, the negotiate works, returns 200 and this response:

```
{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"_5nQwxYYBAczXdW77JAGeQ","connectionToken":"GizQot1b0Gq2epsiM4BA3A","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
```

Which agrees with the way the server is set up.

Comment: Have you inspected the request in dev tools to see the content of it? Have you installed WebSocket support in IIS? Is the certificate trusted?

Comment: Yeah, there is another site with the exact same setup on these exact machines and it works there (it's not the same exact code, it's an older version but the main difference is an update from dotnet 3.1 to 5.0.6).

Comment: Please notice my Edit, maybe something will ring a bell. Thanks @fredrik!

Comment: Guessing that Frederik's answer is probably right on the mark. It's common for the IIS host to not have web-sockets protocol enabled by default. Make sure your IIS is configured correctly, see [IIS/IIS Express Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iisiis-express-support) and [Websockets Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Definitely enabled, like I mentioned it works on a different website hosted on the same IIS

Comment: Just to clarify, it's installed using Server manager on IIS 10. I'ts also enabled which I verified by looking at configuration editor, system.webServer/webSocket section and it says enabled.

Answer (score 1):

2 days I spent on this ... Can't believe the work we do sometimes. Anyways, here's the story.

As part of upgrades, I've also updated IdentityServer to the latest version. Little did I know they changed the algorithm that produces access tokens ever so slightly. In fact, this change resulted in increase of length of the access token by around 100 characters.

Understandably, that's not a big deal so it was not mentioned in any obvious migration guides.

With signalR however, you pass accessToken in the query string. No big deal in general, and certainly no big deal in localhost. However, IIS by default comes with a limit on qs length... I believe you know where I am going with this.

My first edit was actually a good clue. It gave me 404 for no obvious reason. I then forked the default example for signalR, began adding things one by one. Then with authentication, it stopped working. It took a few hours more to spot the access token was actually the culprit.

Anyways, a simple change in web.config resolved the issue:

```
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="8192" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
  <system.webServer>
  ...
```